# Display only queried ID+row PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have my data stored in a MySQL table, which includes an auto_increment ID number (unique) for each new row.

I'd like users to be able to get a certain ID number, using the `$_GET` function.

eg. User loads http://mysite.com/id.php?id=123
Page displays ID number `123` along with the row.

```
echo $row['id'];
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Unit</th> <th>Message</th> <th>Date</th> </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['title'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['description'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['pubDate'];
echo "</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";
```

I'm stuck as to where I put the `$_GET` bit.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should append it to your query (using [`intval`](https://www.php.net/intval) to avoid SQL injection) like this:

```
// use the id in your WHERE clause, convert it to an integer to avoid sql injections
$query = 'SELECT fields FROM table WHERE id = ' . intval($_GET['id']);

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

... do stuff with $row ...
```

Comment: @Dominic Rodger PHP is (sometimes) weird ;). Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Dean - you're still using `$row` before it's set (you use it on line 14, it's set on line 17).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code does not make much sense, since you use `$row` before it was defined.

Secondly, `$result` isn't defined at all, and it should be, for example like this:

```
$id     = intval($_GET['id']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM table WHERE id = '$id'");
```

And now you know how and where to use `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: I only put in a snip of it, it's defined earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
$res = mysql_query ($query);
$exist = mysql_num_rows($res);
if ($exist) {
   $row = mysqlfetch_assoc($res);
   ...
}
```

Comment: `yourpage.com?id='; DELETE * FROM Table; SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id='3`

Comment: This query will not work, because data and fields are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Dont waste your time doing the comparison afterwards, you'll save yourself alot of time by adding it to the original query

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = "SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE id=$id";
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Couldnt work out how to put it in there though.

Thanks for the elaboration.